# How to use groupby agg functions in pandas without deleting rows?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is my DataFrame:

```
`df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 1], ['A', 2], ['A', 3], ['B', 1], ['B', 2]],
                   columns=['Key', 'Value'])`
```

|  | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 2 | A | 3 |
| 3 | B | 1 |
| 4 | B | 2 |

When I am using...

```
`df.groupby(['Key']).count()`
```

...the output is:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |

But I want my output to be:

|  | Key | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | A | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | A | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | B | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | B | 2 | 2 |

(I didn't find a solution in the forum, thanks for the help.)

Answer (score 2):

you probably want `transform` which preserves the original shape:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Key']).transform("count")

  Key  Value  Count
0   A      1      3
1   A      2      3
2   A      3      3
3   B      1      2
4   B      2      2
```

Comment: It's a duplicate.